# How to use multiple sections in one interface asp.net core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-6.0

I have multiple sections in my appsettings.json file that in ASP.NET Core 6 application.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "OracleSettings": {
    "Host": "host.com",
    "Port": "1521"
  },
  "ElasticSettings": {
    "Hosts": "elastic.com"
  },
  "RedisSettings": {
    "Ip": "redis.com",
    "Timeout": 1,
    "Duration": 50
  }  
}
```

And I have created classes for sections.

```
public class OracleSettings
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
}

public class ElasticSettings
{
    public string Hosts { get; set; }
}

public class RedisSettings
{
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public int Timout { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
}
```

I want to access all settings using only one interface named `IApplciationSettings`.

```
public interface IApplciationSettings
{
    OracleSettings OracleSettings { get; set; }
    ElasticSettings ElasticSettings { get; set; }
    RedisSettings RedisSettings { get; set; }
}
```

adding the builder services:

```
builder.Services.Configure<ElasticSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ElasticSettings)));
builder.Services.Configure<OracleSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(OracleSettings)));
builder.Services.Configure<RedisSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(RedisSettings)));
```

So I want to bind to IApplciationSettings interface all configurations and use it in constructor dependency injections like following:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    readonly IProductService productService;

    public PoructController(
        IApplciationSettings settings, IProductService productService)
    {
        this.productService = productService;
        
        var oraclesetting = settings.OracleSettings;
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you require an `IApplciationSettings` interface? Can this class be a simple data class like `OracleSettings` and `ElasticSettings` are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a concrete implementation of `IApplciationSettings`

```
public class ApplciationSettings : IApplciationSettings {
    public OracleSettings OracleSettings { get; set; }
    public ElasticSettings ElasticSettings { get; set; }
    public RedisSettings RedisSettings { get; set; }
}
```

Extract the settings directly from configuration and add it to the dependency injection service container.

```
//...

ApplciationSettings settings = builder.Configuration.Get<ApplciationSettings>();

if(settings == null) throw new Exception("message here"); //fail early

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IApplciationSettings>(settings);

//...
```

[`ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get) extension method binds and returns the specified type.

> Attempts to bind the configuration instance to a new instance of type T. If this configuration section has a value, that will be used. Otherwise binding by matching property names against configuration keys recursively.

This will allow `IApplciationSettings` to be injected as desired without having to be tightly coupled to `IOptions`.

Reference [Bind hierarchical configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Class base on your IApplicationSettings and in Program you write this:

`builder.Services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(builder.Configuration);`

then in your constructor you

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    readonly IProductService productService;

    public PoructController(IOptions<ApplicationSettings> settings, IProductService productService)
    {
        this.productService = productService;
        
        var oraclesetting = settings.Value.OracleSettings;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use IOptions in my classes.

Comment: settings.Value return the whole object applicationSettings.... if you not want that... in programa.cs you can extract IOptions<ApplicationSettings> and then registry like scoped ... but isn't so elegant

```var appSettings = Builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApplicationSettings>>().Value; builder.Services.AddScoped<IApplicationSettings, ApplicationSettings>();```